# Local development with Google Cloud Spring dependencies

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm currently implementing a spring boot application with quite a few dependencies on google cloud services like `PubSub`. The spring boot autoconfiguration creates a number of beans for me.
For example a `MessagingGateway` implementation and a `PubSubTemplate`.

Now I have the following artifacts:

```
@Service
public class MyServiceImpl implements MyService {
    private final PubsubOutboundGateway messagingGateway;

    public MyServiceImpl(PubsubOutboundGateway messagingGateway) {
        this.messagingGateway = messagingGateway;
    }

    @Override
    public void sendToPubSub(String s) {
        messagingGateway.sendTest(s);
    }
}
```

```
@MessagingGateway
@Component
public interface PubsubOutboundGateway {
    @Gateway(requestChannel = "myChannel" )
    void sendTest(String test);
}
```

```
@Configuration
public class Channels {
    @Bean
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "myChannel")
    public MessageHandler messageSender(PubSubTemplate pubsubTemplate) {
        return new PubSubMessageHandler(pubsubTemplate, "my-topic");
    }
}
```

When I turn off pubsub for local development, I get the following error

`Consider defining a bean of type 'com.google.cloud.spring.pubsub.core.PubSubTemplate' in your configuration.`

But what I really want is a local PubsubOutboundGateway that just prints the messages.
I can achieve this by adding `@Profile("!local")` to `PubsubOutboundGateway` and `Channels` and implement a `PubsubOutboundGatewayLocalImpl`. But this seems like a hack.

How can perform local development without having an active GCP key etc. setup? Or does that just hinder development and I should use an active key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest to use the [Pub/Sub emulator](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/emulator), in order to get as close to the remote environment as possible.